# standard place to put development/code files in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, filesystem

I am setting up my development environment on Ubuntu and I was wondering what the standard is on where I should place custom development projects on the file system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside ~/ somewhere.  It's peculiar to IDE, although a work, dev, workspace, etc folder is common.

If you need replication most IDEs have git, svn, or mercurial integration.